# how do I to display an error message on a page using jQuery inside php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML form with a submit button that will post status on a page when  a user clicks the submit button without typing anything into the form field. I want php to echo a very simple error message on the same page. In this case, "This status update appears to be blank. Please write something..."

In short... my need can be seen on Facebook; when you click on a post without writing something in the status field  then a div will pop up in the middle of the screen with some error message. I think this can be done with jQuery. I have tried all I can. Please, can somebody help me achieve this?

Below is my PHP script and I want the action to be written at the else condition - line 42 of my code.

```
<?php 




//setting connection variables
$hostname = "localhost";
$username= "root";
$password ="";
$db= "cemembers";

$_SESSION['Email'] = "FirstName"; $_SESSION['FirstName'] = 1; 

$globalstatus = $_POST['globalstatus'];
$post_name =$_POST["postname"];

//connect to database
$mysqli_db = new mysqli( $hostname, $username, $password, $db);


/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}

if(!empty($globalstatus) ){

    $sql='INSERT INTO user_post(user_post,post_name) VALUES 
(?,?)';

$requery = $mysqli_db->prepare($sql);
$requery->bind_param("ss", $post_name, $globalstatus);


    if ($requery->execute()){

        header("location:go.php");

        }
    }
    else{

        $post_fail = "<div class='postfail'>"."Post field appears to be blank. Please Write something"."</div>";
        echo $post_fail;
        echo header("location:go.php");
        };



?>
```

Comment: just remove `echo header("location:go.php");` which doesn't make sense anyway. You can't print a redirect.

Comment: ok ...I've tried that now but the div didn't show up...it only redirect back to go.php @developerwjk

Comment: you also need to fix your indenting and figure out where you screwed up the `{` and `}` pairing because its off.

Comment: Sounds like you need client-side validation plus bootstrap modal or jQuery UI modal or something of the sort. You would need ajax here ... but not for such an error (client-side). Thus, you PHP does not come into play at all. Can you, therefore, provide your HTML form plus the JavaScript to go with it in lieu of your PHP script.

Comment: yes...something like that. I thought i could use php to echo something simple on the page.... ok then let me try using jQuery form validation@PeterKA

Answer (score 0):

You would make things lots easier if you checked for (formal) correctness **before** submitting using JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(".errpopup").click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});

function toBeCalledOnSubmit() {
    if (!$("#commentbox").val()) {
        $("#commentbox").addClass("submiterr");
        //You can also use alert(); instead of the following line
        $(body).append("<div class=\"errpopup\">Put error message here</div");
        return false;
    else {
        $("#commentbox").removeClass("submiterr");
        return true;
    }
}
```

And CSS:

```
.submiterr {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.errpopup {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 42; /* higher than all the other z-indices */
    width: 300px; height: 150px; /* or what you like*/
    top: auto; bottom: auto; left: auto; right: auto;
}
```

Comment: I can see your logic...but my php code is not allowing it to run...it always redirect back to go.php@the_Seppi

Comment: I don't understand what you're attempting to say... in this approach, PHP wouldn't even be used before the input was formally correct...